# TF Object Detection API: save metrics to disk

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm trying to dump evaluation metrics on disk after each evaluation step during Object Detection API training. For example dump AP to the model_dir with the name of the step on which it was evaluated. This framework uses `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate`. So my best guess I should create a hook for either `tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec` or `tf.estimator.EvalSpec` using `tf.train.SessionRunHook`.

However, I have doubts that it's even a right direction. The object detection metrics (i.e. AP) is printed by default while calculation is finished, and it seems to be calculated outside of TF graph. I can't dump it from there since global_step and model_dir are not accessible during that call.